# I wanted to know in the statement $5$ added to a number divided by $3$ whether we divide after adding $5$ or the number is already divided?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

If we were to convert the the statement

> $5$ added to a number divided by $3$

to equation.

Would it be $5+\frac x3$ or $\frac{5+x}3$?

Comment: It's ambiguous.  Ask the person saying it to explain themselves.  (It's some words in English.  It is not a well-formed mathematical expression.)

Comment: It depends if the $5+x$ is in parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"five added to a number *barely perceptible pause* divided by three" would be $\frac {5+x}3$.

"five added to *barely perceptible pronouncing of the word 'to' for just a nanosecond longer then normal* a number divided by three *with the words 'a number divided by three' just barely noticeably rushed*" would be $5 + \frac x3$.

English words are not necessarily well-formed mathematical statements and the meaning of those words is ambiguous.  We must ask the speaker to elaborate.

Comment: It was in written form, that's why I was confused too otherwise the pause determines it.

Answer (score 1):

I personally vote for $5+\frac x3$, just based on my gut.

Ultimately, however, you will have to ask the author of the phrase (or read their mind). There is no way to be absolutely certain.

Or try both, keep calculating, see what you get, and check whether only one result makes sense in the end.

Answer (score 1):

It's ambiguous. You could parse it as "(5 added to a number) divided by 3" or "5 added to (a number divided by 3)".

When speaking the phrase, you can sort of indicate the "parenthesis" with a pause.

Comment: Absolutely, right but what can we do the sentence I read didn't have any parantheses

Comment: "what can we do the sentence"  Ignore it.  Yell at it.  Pound on the author's door and demand they explain themselves.  It's just a bunch of words.  It's not a well-formed mathematical expression.  The *author* failed.  We didn't.  There is nothing for us to do.  And it's not our responsibility to do anything.

Comment: I suppose if we declare: "we can directly corelate written words to mathematical expression" we have no choice but to take "five plus a number divided by 3" as "5 + x \div 3" which is "5 + (x \div 3) = 5 + \frac x 3" because that is what the words were one after another were.  And had they *wanted* to say $\frac {5+x}3$ they have had to have words indicating parenthesis.  But that assumes there *is* a direct mapping ant the author is aware of it *and* its pitfalls.  ... I am more inclined to say it is a bunch of ambiguous words and *not* a well formed mathematical expression, and walk away.